# Cordova plugin undefined during Vue mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cordova

I have an mobile with Cordova and Vue.js.

For HTTP request I use this plugin : https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http

The plugin work really well. Except when I want to use it during the mounted stage of App.vue.

```
mounted() {
  windows.cordova.plugin.http.get('my-url') ....
}
```

I get this following error :

```
Cannot read property 'http' of undefined
```

But if i do a console.log(window.cordova.plugin) in my browser, plugin is defined.

Is there a way in Vue.js to use a function after mounted()?

Or, is there a way to load Cordova plugins before mounted()?

Comment: Sorry i wrote 'windows' instead of 'window' for 'window.cordova.plugin.http.get'

Comment: How is the plugin installed?

Comment: The plugin is installed with 'cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http'